# Back button not working when modal is displayed

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have create a component to display modal as follows:

```
    export default class Modal extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          animationType: 'slide',
          modalVisible: true,
          props: null,
          color: '#282727'
        }
      }
      hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({
          modalVisible: false,
        })
      }


      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Modal
              animationType={this.state.animationType}
              transparent={true}
              visible={this.state.modalVisible}
              onRequestClose={() => this.hideModal}
              onOrientationChange={evt => this.setState({ currentOrientation: evt.nativeEvent.orientation })}
            >
              <Container>

                <Content style={styles.container}>

                  <Card style={styles.card}>
                    <Text></Text>
                  </Card>
                </Content>
              </Container >
            </Modal >
          </View >
        );
      }
    }
```

I am using calling the modal from the following component as follows:

```
      import customModal from '../customModal';

      export default class CardsList extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            Modal: null,
          }
        }
        showModal = () => {
          let Modal = <customModal />;
          this.setState({ Modal })
        }
        hideModal = () => {
          this.setState({
            Modal: null
          })
        render() {
          return (
            <Container style={{ backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7' }}>
              <Content>
                {this.state.Modal}
              </Content>
              <Button onPress={this.showMenu}>
                   Show Modal
              </Button>
            </Container>
          );
        }
      }
```

I am facing following issue:

1. Back button not working when modal is displayed on screen.